# JavaScript - getElementById not understanding my input

Tags: javascript

So I have this code:

```
window.onload = make_buttons ('"calc"');

function make_buttons (id) {
    console.log (id);
    var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(id.input);
    for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
        var btn = document.createElement ("BUTTON");
        var t = document.createTextNode (i);
        btn.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById(id).appendChild(id.btn);    
    }
};
```

Basicly I insert the id of the div element in the `make_buttons ()` function and then it should create everything that I ask it to create for me. 
But for some reason this method throws me an error which says that `getElementById` is given a NULL value. The `console.log (id)` shows that id is "calc" `getElementByID` should have "calc" inside of the (). Why is it so?

Also when I have created all thoes buttons, can I just add a `.onclick=` after the `.append.Child()` to make it have a on click event also?

Comment: Do your id really contain quotes ? You probably should have `make_buttons ('calc');`

Comment: Console log shows that the id is `"calc"` which I think is right?

Comment: @Veske: No, it should just show `calc`, without quotation marks. Compare `console.log('foo');` vs `console.log('"foo"');`. The quotation marks are just *delimiters* for the parser to indicate where a string value starts and ends. They are not supposed to be part of the string value itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The console always display quotes for strings, that doesn't mean that your string contains quotes. Your id is `calc`, not `"calc"`.

2) As noticed by Felix, you're assigning to `window.onload` the result of the function instead of the function.

Replace

```
window.onload = make_buttons ('"calc"');
```

with

```
window.onload = function(){ make_buttons ('calc'); }
```

Comment: He also shouldn't call the function at that moment.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm sure you're right but I don't understand your remark.

Comment: He is assigning the return value to `window.onload`: `window.onload = make_buttons('...');`.

Comment: @FelixKling How could I miss that... If you can fix it again, don't hesitate, I made it CW ;)

Comment: Using this gives this error: `Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null. `

Comment: Yep, works now!  Also the last question I had, can I just add the .onclick event after the appendChild too`?

Comment: do you want to attach `onclick` on input which is just appended?

Comment: Yes, so that it would print the number into the form.

Answer (score 2):

problem is `id.input` on    `document.getElementById(id).appendChild(id.input);`

You are passing string as id. but appending `id.input` in parent element which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you, try using the body on load

```
<body onload="make_buttons('calc');">


</body>
```

Comment: Still giving the error: `Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.`

Comment: That makes me believe that the node is not found so you do not have an proper id, I can try to get some sample code in a bit, I would highly advise looking into JQuery it makes things like this easy :D Using jquery i would type like $('#mydiv').append('<input id="input' + i + ' ">');

Comment: Haven't learned much JQuery yet but I guess I will take a look at it then.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned the ID to the input you're creating.  The input is in the document, but it doesn't have the ID you're passing at the time you're trying to access it.